# Preparing Cassandra SELECT Statements in Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to run prepared select queries against a Cassandra table.

The table is defined as such:

```
class EmailAddressLookup(Model, ModelOperations, JSONSerializer):
    __table_name__ = 'email_address_lookup'

    email_address = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    user_id = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
```

My INSERT works great.  It looks like this:

```
i_email_lookup = session.prepare("""INSERT INTO email_address_lookup (user_id, email_address) VALUES (?, ?)""")

session.execute(i_email_lookup, (user_id, email_address))
```

However, my SELECT is not working.  It looks like this:

```
s_email_lookup_by_email = session.prepare('SELECT user_id FROM email_address_lookup WHERE "email_address"=?')

session.execute(s_email_lookup_by_email, email_address)
```

Here's the traceback when email_address is a 27-char string:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thisguy/Documents/my_proj/api/models/case.py", line 428, in _lookup_usin_email
    matches = my_projcluster.select_email_lookup_by_email(self.email)
  File "/home/thisguy/Documents/my_proj/api/utils/decorators.py", line 14, in newfunc
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thisguy/Documents/my_proj/api/models/my_projcluster.py", line 203, in select_email_lookup_by_email
    session.execute(s_email_lookup_by_email, (email_address))
  File "/home/thisguy/.Envs/my_proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1403, in execute
    future = self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace)
  File "/home/thisguy/.Envs/my_proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1452, in execute_async
    future = self._create_response_future(query, parameters, trace)
  File "/home/thisguy/.Envs/my_proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1464, in _create_response_future
    query = query.bind(parameters)
  File "/home/thisguy/.Envs/my_proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 390, in bind
    return BoundStatement(self).bind(values)
  File "/home/thisguy/.Envs/my_proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 486, in bind
    (len(values), len(col_meta)))
ValueError: Too many arguments provided to bind() (got 27, expected 1)
```

Okay, so Python tried to turn a 27-char string into 27 args?  Let's wrap it in a tuple:

```
session.execute(s_email_lookup_by_email, (email_address, ))
```

This prevents the traceback, but the query returns None even when the data base certainly has a matching email address in it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This:

```
session.execute(s_email_lookup_by_email, (email_address))
```

doesn't really pass a 1-tuple to the `execute` method.

In python, to create a 1-tuple you need to follow the first element with a comma:

```
session.execute(s_email_lookup_by_email, (email_address,))
```

otherwise the parentheses are interpreted as grouping operators and that makes `(email_address)` equivalent to `email_address` without parentheses.

Comment: Good catch!   Setting up the tuple properly does prevent the error from happening, but now the execute() is returning None, even though I am certain there is matching data in the table.

Comment: @AdamSteele I think the quotes around `"email_address"` in the `WHERE` clause are unnecessary. Maybe CQL tries to compare the parameter with `"email_address"` string and results in an almost-always false condition.

Comment: Good idea.  Sadly, it seems to return None with or without the quotes.

Comment: I'd try running the same query in cqlsh and see if it returns something there.

Comment: It's tough to run this query in cqlsh because this is just temporary data that I'm unittesting with.

However, when I run the query using CQLEngine, it's coming back with results:

`EmailAddressLookup.objects.filter(email_address=self.email).all() 
`

Comment: I am a fool.  Your original answer about setting up that tuple was in fact correct. I was not properly testing the return value of session.execute()